# Undefined reference in static library to c++11 atomic

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, stdatomic

I have a problem when using a static library that I create beforehand in a project. This static library uses [c++11 atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic). Everything compiles well and my static library is created. However, when I try to use it in another project, at link time I got the following error:

```
 src/engine/bin/libengine.a(Compound.cpp.o): In function`Job::restart()':
 (.text._ZN3Job7restartEv[_ZN3Job7restartEv]+0x30): undefined reference to `__atomic_exchange_1'
```

Where Compound.cpp.o is when of the object files of the library.
Here is  the Makefile I am using to create my library:

```
CC=k1-g++
CPPFLAGS=-c -I$(GENERIC_INCLUDE_DIR) -I$(SPECIFIC_INCLUDE_DIR) -Os -std=c++11 -mos=nodeos 
CXXFLAGS=-c -I$(GENERIC_INCLUDE_DIR) -I$(SPECIFIC_INCLUDE_DIR) -Os -std=c++11 -mos=nodeos 
LFLAGS=-pthread -lnodeos -latomic 

GENERIC_INCLUDE_DIR=generic/include
SPECIFIC_INCLUDE_DIR=specific/include
GENERIC_SRC_DIR=generic/src
SPECIFIC_SRC_DIR=specific/src


LIB = libengine.a
BIN_DIR=bin

vpath %.cpp $(GENERIC_SRC_DIR) $(SPECIFIC_SRC_DIR)
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(GENERIC_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp $(SPECIFIC_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
SOURCES := $(notdir $(SOURCES))
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.cpp,$(BIN_DIR)/%.cpp.o,$(SOURCES))



all: $(OBJECTS) $(LIB)

$(LIB): $(OBJECTS)
    ar -cr $(BIN_DIR)/$@ $^

#$(BIN_DIR)/%.cpp.o: $(GENERIC_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
#   $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $< $(LFLAGS) -o $@

$(BIN_DIR)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $< $(LFLAGS) -o $@




.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(BIN_DIR)/*
```

Any thought on this?

Comment: Which version of gcc are you using? If it's gcc 4.7, libatomic is not supplied due to time constraints. Details here: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM

Comment: I am using gcc version 4.9.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the target platform you're compiling for doesn't support 1-byte atomic instructions natively, so you will need to use the GCC library that provides atomic operations as library functions.

Link with `-latomic` to link to GCC's `libatomic`

Your makefile tries to do that, but you only use `LFLAGS` when compiling `.o` objects, which doesn't do any linking, so the `-latomic` option is not used when it matters.

You need to use the `-latomic` option when compiling the program that *uses* your static library, not when you create the static library.

The makefile is a bit of a mess. It's useless to use linker flags when compiling objects, and conventionally `CPPFLAGS` contains flags for the preprocessor, not compilation flags such as `-c` and `-Os`.

Comment: @Marcel's question shows the linker flags used (makefile 4th line from the top) and s/he's already linking to libatomic with -latomic.

Comment: @VijayVaradan, nope. Read the makefile again.

Comment: Your edit clarified that LFLAGS was not being passed to the linker. Good catch.

Comment: @VijayVaradan plus this makefile is the one that creates the static library, the `-latomic` option needs to be used when compiling the program that _uses_ the static library.

Comment: isn't linking to libatomic by the program needed only if the program itself calls functions from libatomic? Or if the static lib headers files included in the program make libatomic calls which would need to be resolved when linking the program. If not for these 2 cases, it would be sufficient if the static lib alone links to it, right? At least that's been my experience (primarily) with Windows programming.

Comment: @VijayVaradan, no. That would be the case if the OP was creating a dynamic library, and linked the dynamic library to libatomic.so, but that's not what is happening. A static library cannot link to another library, a static library is just a very simple archive that contains object files. When you link to a static library you need to resolve all the references in the static lib.

Comment: Actually, in Windows you can join multiple static libs to one another using the lib.exe tool, but I'll stop here - we're starting to get OT. Cheers.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I am trying to run an application on a distributed platform (kalray mppa). Now, when i add -latomic the platform could not find atomic library. Does that means that there is no support for this library on that platform?

Comment: @Marcel, do you mean it can't find it when linking your application, or when running it? If it can't find it when linking, it probably means the platform doesn't support the library (talk to the vendor who supplied the compiler and ask them to port libatomic to their platform).

Comment: That was my guess. I already created a ticket on their support website.
Many thanks